# Passing arguments to reselect createStructuredSelector

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

I am using `createStructuredSelector` from `reselect` so my code looks like:

```
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  event: makeSelectEvent(),
  relatedEvents: makeSelectRelatedEvents(),
  loading: makeSelectLoading(),
  error: makeSelectError()
})
```

I am having a problem passing arguments to selectors. I am able to do `event: makeSelectEvent()`, which could select/return something like `currentEvent`. However, I am unable to get the version with arguments, conceptually `event: id => makeSelectEvent(id)` working.

I have seen this discussed online in a few places, like [there](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/issues/772). Nothing that I saw people suggest worked for me.

Any recommendations?

Comment: do you figure out the right way to do this?

Comment: I would say, in a way... If you want to pass arguments, do not use reselect.